# How to plot graphs nicely in Python

Tags: python, graphviz, networkx

As part of my UI, I want to display graphs.  The requirements are:

1. The graph must respond to events (e.g. mouse clicks).
2. If the graph is directed I want nice arrows.
3. If there are several edges spanning two nodes I want to display several edges.
4. The layout must be nice.

Now, there are two libraries: networkx and graphviz that can do some of those things.  networkx can do 1 and (with some major hacks) 2.  graphviz can do 2 and 3.  4 can be done by either library.

I would actually prefer to use graphviz because that would eliminate some dependencies; however, its inability to interact with matplotlib is a major problem.

Therefore, at the moment I am stuck with networkx, have to use a hack for arrows and abandon the idea of parallel edges.

My question is: Is this the state of the art or there is some other approach I could try?

Another question: Is it better to use a different language for graph visualization?  For example, would it make sense to move all UI/visualization to JavaScript, while keeping Python only for data analysis?

Comment: just use d3 like everyone else ;)

Comment: What is the size of the graph you want to display?

Comment: Well, I asked a specific question, which was how to achieve specific functionality in Python and if that's not possible, if I should switch to another language.  And got a very good answer that indeed it's not worth it and I should switch to a JavaScript library.  I don't understand this "on hold" and "off topic" thing - do you guys really want only questions of the type "how do I write this for loop"?

Comment: The question is [being discussed on Meta Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/305879/215552).